# Sending messages to MSMQ using a WCF service

Tags: msmq

I've created a WCF service to send a message to an MSMQ, I can get it to run and it looks like the message was sent but when looking at the queue it's not there.  I've verified and the queue is not a transactional queue. Security is open so that everyone can send messages but I'm wondering if there are other places to set security?  Here is my code I'm using.

```
Dim mq As MessageQueue
Dim msg As Message
Dim queueName As String = "webdevbvm.labsafety.com\emailsubscriptions"

Try
   msg = New Message("Test")
   msg.Priority = MessagePriority.Highest

   If (MessageQueue.Exists(queueName)) Then
       mq = New MessageQueue(queueName)
   msg.ResponseQueue = mq
   msg.UseJournalQueue = True
   msg.Label = "Test Message"
   msg.Body = "This is only a test"
   mq.Send(msg)
   Console.WriteLine("Message sent.")
   End If
Catch ex As MessageQueueException
   Console.WriteLine("MSMQ Error: " + ex.ToString())
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString())
Finally
   mq.Close()
End Try
```

I get no errors but I do see the messages in my outgoing queue from the machine that is running the program.  It shows the queue exists and if I change the queue name to one that doesn't exist it doesn't go into the IF statement so I know it's seeing the queue just not sending the file.  If it helps I'm running the program locally on a laptop and the queue it's sending too is on a Windows 2003 server.

Comment: Do you see the "Message Sent." from your console.writeline command?

Comment: What happens if the Queue doesn't exist? ru-roh...... boom. (psst: add a check to create the queue, if it doesn't exist Or handle that as an error).

Comment: Removed WCF related tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks marc for your response but I figured out what needed to be done.  Basially I was using the wrong queue name.  I didn't have "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:" in front of the queue name.  Once I put that it was good to go.  thanks again.

Robert

Comment: Robert, if this is the answer, then you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look like a WCF service to me - seems you're using the base `System.Net.Messaging` API to send message to your queue....

Check out some of these link to see how to use WCF to send messages to MSMQ:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx
- http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/28/wcf-and-msmq.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx
- http://www.devx.com/architect/Article/41058

Marc

Comment: why would a wcf service drop a message into MSMQ directly?

Comment: why not sent it from the WCF service **using** WCF ??

Comment: that is what I'm trying to figure out.  I forgot to put in the post that I'm a newbie to both WCF services and MSMQ.  I'll check out these articles and see what happens.  thanks

Comment: @Robert: OK, check out if those resources make sense to you and answer your question and if not come back and ask again ;-)